# окно watches (codeblocks). Как с этим работать?

Tags: codeblocks

1: 
[image: У меня окно watches выглядит так]
У меня окно watches выглядит иначе. Ни одна переменная не отображается. Не понимаю, как добавить переменную в окно. При нажатии ПКМ по переменной в программе в списке команд нет watch. Что делать?
Не могу нигде найти информацию..

Comment: Когда вы при дебаге остановитесь на точке останова внутри какой-либо функции, в этом окне будут автоматически отображаться переменные и их значения. Руками туда добавлять ничего не надо.

Comment: @zed Руками добавлять можно. Например если нужно значение выражения, или глобальной переменной.

Comment: @zed  Отладчик игнорит, видимо, точку остановf. Запускаешь, вводишь данные.. потом появляется сообщение "Отладчик завершился со статусом 0", но с окном watches ничего не происходит... Может отладчик какой-то не тот выбран?

Comment: Кто ж знает, что у вас там выбрано? Освоить IDE это большое дело, для абсолютного новичка. Я бы рекомендовал установить крайнюю ночную сборку CB (выкладывают [тут](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/board,20.0.html)), плюс, крайнюю версию [mingw-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) и разобраться как настроить CB на использование этого компилятора и отладчика. Возможно придётся почитать wiki или посмотреть на ютубе обзорчики. Признаком того, что всё настроено верно, будет то, что вы сможете скомпилировать простейший HelloWorld и поставить брекпоинт в интересующем месте.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы посмотреть\изменить переменные, надо компилировать под debug и запустить отладчик (красный треугольник).